# How do I merge results from target page to current page in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Need example in scrapy on how to get a link from one page, then follow this link, get more info from the linked page, and merge back with some data from first page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Partially fill your item on the first page, and the put it in your request's meta. When the callback for the next page is called, it can take the partially filled request, put more data into it, and then return it.

Comment: thanks, i got the inner link togoto in my var: links[i] then i tried inside a loop (for each outer page) to do this:         for i in range(0,len(categories)):
            print categories[i] + ' : ' + links[i]
            item = LectscrapItem()
            item['category'] = categories[i]
            yield FormRequest(links[i],method='GET',callback=self.parseVideo,
                meta={'item':item})  and inside parseVideo i did: print 'im here' i don't see i'm here printed... anything i'm doing wrong please?

Comment: @Jason, i haven't used FormRequest, but... `FormRequest(links[i],method='GET',callback=self.parseVideo, meta={'item':item})` why you need FormRequest without `formdata` argument? why not a simple Request?

Comment: ok so i updated to request and now it looks like this: '            print 'initem going to video'
            yield Request(links[i], callback=self.parseVideo)
' and in my method: parseVideo i have this: '    def parseVideo(self, response):
        print 'inhere'        
'  however while i do get the first printing i get no 'inhere' printing... i don't understand why its not called..

Answer (score 8):

An example from [scrapy documntation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                         callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

Answer (score 7):

More information on passing the `meta` data and request objects is specifically described in this part of the documentation:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

This question is also related to: [Scrapy: Follow link to get additional Item data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334522/scrapy-follow-link-to-get-additional-item-data)

Answer (score 4):

A bit illustration of Scrapy documentation code

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/main_page.html",callback=parse_page1)
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url ##extracts http://www.example.com/main_page.html
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['my_meta_item'] = item ## passing item in the meta dictionary
    ##alternatively you can follow as below
    ##request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",meta={'my_meta_item':item},callback=self.parse_page2)
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['my_meta_item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url ##extracts http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    return item
```