# Scrapy: Follow link to get additional Item data?

Tags: hyperlink, callback, scrapy

I don't have a specific code issue I'm just not sure how to approach the following problem logistically with the Scrapy framework:

The structure of the data I want to scrape is typically a table row for each item.  Straightforward enough, right?

Ultimately I want to scrape the **Title**, **Due Date**, and **Details** for each row.  **Title** and **Due Date** are immediately available on the page...

BUT the **Details** themselves aren't in the table -- but rather, a link to the page containing the details (if that doesn't make sense here's a table):

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|             Title              |    Due Date    |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| Job Title (Clickable Link)     |    1/1/2012    |
| Other Job (Link)               |    3/2/2012    |
|--------------------------------|----------------|
```

I'm afraid I still don't know how to logistically pass the item around with callbacks and requests, even after reading through the *CrawlSpider* section of the Scrapy documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i merge results from target page to current page in scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467700/how-do-i-merge-results-from-target-page-to-current-page-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please, first read the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) to understand what i say.

The answer:

To scrape additional fields which are on other pages, in a parse method extract URL of the page with additional info, create and return from that parse method a Request object with that URL and pass already extracted data via its `meta` parameter.

[how do i merge results from target page to current page in scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467700/how-do-i-merge-results-from-target-page-to-current-page-in-scrapy)

Comment: @fortuneRice, not sure if the examples are up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150053 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910357/how-can-i-use-multiple-requests-and-pass-items-in-between-them-in-scrapy-python/13911764#13911764

Comment: this is the relevant part of the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

Comment: Thanks @tback. OP's RTFD is just not a helpful way of formulating an answer.

Answer (score 25):

An example from [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

```python
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Python `functools.partial` to pass an `item` or any other serializable data via additional arguments to the next Scrapy callback.

Something like:

```python
import functools

# Inside your Spider class:

def parse(self, response):
  # ...
  # Process the first response here, populate item and next_url.
  # ...
  callback = functools.partial(self.parse_next, item, someotherarg)
  return Request(next_url, callback=callback)

def parse_next(self, item, someotherarg, response):
  # ...
  # Process the second response here.
  # ...
  return item
```