# In scrapy I'm trying to retrieve a list of links then scrape data from these links in a single scrapy file. My csv file returns a list of xpaths.

Tags: python, html, csv, xpath, scrapy

I tried using igaggini's example on this page but can;t seem to get it to work with my code. [Scrapy: Follow link to get additional Item data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334522/scrapy-follow-link-to-get-additional-item-data)

I'm pretty sure I have the right xpaths, the output should be the second paragraph in the first div of the scraped links from the countries page.

Here is my main file, recursive.py.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from bathUni.items import BathuniItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'recursive'
allowed_domains = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/']
start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = []

    #scrap main page to get row links
    for i in range(1, 154):
        xpath = ('//*[@id="all-countries"]/li[*]/ul/li[*]/a' .format (i+1))
        link = hxs.select(xpath).extract()
        links.append(link)

    #parse links to get content of the linked pages
    for link in links:
        item = BathuniItem()
        item ['Qualification'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/div[1]/p[2]')

        yield item
```

Here is my items file

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class BathuniItem(Item):
    Country = Field()
    Qualification = Field()
```

And the output I receive is not what I want it to do, my csv file is full of these -

```
<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//*[@id="all-countries"]/li[*]/ul/li[*]/a' data=u'<a href="/international/countries/albani'>
```

Comment: Just a hint: all that `[*]` predicates are unnecessary, eg. you match all list items that have any child elements, and then select those that are unsorted lists (which only returns a result if there are children anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You should call `.extract()` on the selector to get a useful value instead of a `SelectorList`

```
item ['Qualification'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/div[1]/p[2]').extract()
```

Another thing, I understand you want to fetch the pages corresponding to the links

```
#parse links to get content of the linked pages
for link in links:
    item = BathuniItem()
    item ['Qualification'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/div[1]/p[2]').extract()

    yield item
```

That code will not fetch these linked pages, you need to yield additional `Requests` to tell Scrapy to download them.

You should do something like:

```
    start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = []

        #scrap main page to get row links
        for i in range(1, 154):
            xpath = ('//*[@id="all-countries"]/li[*]/ul/li[*]/a/@href' .format (i+1))
            links.extend(hxs.select(xpath).extract())

        #parse links to get content of the linked pages
        for link in links:
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_linkpage)

    def parse_linkpage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = BathuniItem()
        item ['Qualification'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/div[1]/p[2]').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: After trying to use this code I'm getting a TypeError  Request url must be str or unicode, got list:

Comment: I fixed that by using `links.extend(hxs.select(xpath).extract())`, `.extract())` returning a list.