# Scrapy Spider not following Request callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I have read [Scrapy: Follow link to get additional Item data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334522/scrapy-follow-link-to-get-additional-item-data) and followed it, but it is not working, probably it is sone simple mistake, so I am putting source code of my Spider.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider1(Spider):
    name = "timeanddate"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.timeanddate.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        countries = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="fixed"]//li/a[contains(@href, "/holidays/")]')

        for item in countries:

            link = item.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            country = item.xpath('text()').extract()[0]

            linkToFollow = self.allowed_domains[0] + link + "/#!hol=1"

            print link  # link
            print country  # text in a HTML tag
            print linkToFollow

            request = scrapy.Request(linkToFollow, callback=self.parse_page2)


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        print "XXXXXX"
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        print hxs
```

I am trying too get list of all holidays per for each country, that is what I need to get to another page.

I can not understand why parse_page2 is not called.

Comment: You never return the request in `parse`

Comment: I tired return it, but also it is not working. If you have time please show me with code your idea.

Comment: `yield request` after that `request = scrapy.Request(...)` line.

Comment: I try that also and it did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

I could make your example work using [Link Extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)

Here is an example:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

class TimeAndDateSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "timeanddate"
    allowed_domains = ["timeanddate.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/",
    ]


    rules = (
            Rule (LxmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="fixed"]//li/a[contains(@href, "/holidays/")]',))
                , callback='second_page'),
            ) 

    #2nd page
    def second_page(self,response):
        print "second page - %s" % response.url
```

Will keep trying to make the Request callback example to work

Comment: I have try it and it is not working, not even with yield

Comment: Yes I did read it, now I am trying just to go from one page to another, after that I will add data to Items.

Comment: This code is working. I have one question. In http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml it is said that SgmlLinkExtractor is depreciated. Do you have special reason why you picked it ?

Comment: your code will go to link eg. http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/new-zealand but I want to go to http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/new-zealand/#!hol=1 is this possible to do ? Also after visiting http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/new-zealand/#!hol=1 I would like to go to http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/new-zealand/2016#!hol=1 is this also possible ?