# Scrapy request in a for loop

Tags: python, scrapy, request

So I tried to apply the examples in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334522/scrapy-follow-link-to-get-additional-item-data) but my output is strange:

My item:

```
class Artiste(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    nom = scrapy.Field()
    styles = scrapy.Field()
```

My Scrapy class:

```
class AnnuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "annu"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.livetonight.fr/groupe-musique-dj',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        doc = Artiste()
        for artiste in response.css('.card-musician'):
            details_partial_link = artiste.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            doc['nom'] = artiste.css('.card-musician-title-wrapper').xpath('normalize-space(./h4/text())').get()
            doc['url'] = details_partial_link
            details_link = response.urljoin(details_partial_link)
            request = scrapy.Request(details_link, callback=self.parse_details)
            request.meta['item'] = doc
            print "NOM", doc['nom']
            yield request

    def parse_details(self, response):
        doc = response.meta['item']
        doc['styles'] = response.css('.show-overview-info').xpath('normalize-space(./p/text())')[0].get()
        return doc
```

So, instead of giving me 21 lines with each having their own `nom`,`url`,`styles`I get 21 lines with the same (which is the last of the list) `nom`and `url`and the right `styles`.

Here is the full output:

```
[
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Jazz / Folk / Rock"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Rock / Pop / Folk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Soul / Pop / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Soul / Pop / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Jazz / Pop"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Rock / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Rock / Jazz"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Rock / Pop / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Rock / Pop / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Jazz"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Rock / Blues / Soul"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Rock / Blues / Soul"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Funk / Soul / Pop"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Folk / Soul"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Jazz / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Jazz / Funk"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Jazz / Swing / Musique du monde"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Guinguette / Swing"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Guinguette / Swing"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Jazz / Swing / Pop"},
{"url": "/groupe-musique-dj/4123-remi-dugue-trio", "nom": "R\u00e9mi Dugu\u00e9 Trio", "styles": "Pop / Funk / Dj"}
]
```

What's strange to me is the fact that if I take out the request, my output is perfect. Like with this code:

```
class AnnuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "annu"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.livetonight.fr/groupe-musique-dj',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        doc = Artiste()
        for artiste in response.css('.card-musician'):
            details_partial_link = artiste.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            doc['nom'] = artiste.css('.card-musician-title-wrapper').xpath('normalize-space(./h4/text())').get()
            doc['url'] = details_partial_link
            details_link = response.urljoin(details_partial_link)
            yield doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the doc declaration to inside the loop:

```py
def parse(self, response):
        for artiste in response.css('.card-musician'):
           doc = Artiste()
           ...
```

Comment: Haha, very well played. Been stuck for hours on that .. I guess I should go to sleep!